# ¿System.Timers.Timer comparte recursos entre Hilos?

Tags: c#, hilos

tengo una duda, ¿Los timers generan un hilo nuevo cada vez que vuelve a empezar el contador? Ejemplo. yo tengo una clase en la cual inicializo un timer y una variable tiempo en el cual ire guardando el tiempo que ha pasado desde que inicio el timer (Es un ejemplo, se que pueden haber otras maneras de sacar el tiempo general, pero para explicar mi duda utilice este ejemplo)

```
public class Prueba{
   System.Timers.Timer Timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000); // Un intervalo de un segundo

   private TimeStamp Time;

   public void Start(){
       Timer.Elapsed += Accion;
       Timer.Start();
   }

   public void Accion(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e){
        Timestamp.Add(new Timestamp(0,0,10)); // Agregamos 10 segundos
   }
}
```

Mi duda es: Cada vez que se ejecute el evento Elapsed modificara a la misma propiedad Time? o cada una tendra su propiedad Time separada? ya que a lo que entiendo los timers funcionan en otro hilo

Comment: El timer funciona en otro hilo (no lo recuerdo) pero tu evento, esta en el hilo principal (o en el hilo donde este esa clase)... bastaba con que lo probaras...

Comment: @gbianchi lo probe en otra aplicacion, pero lo que me pasaba en ella es que a veces me mostraba los valores correctos y a veces no, por me dio esa duda

Comment: @LuisGarcia ahí la cosa era entonces revisar esa otra aplicación :)

Comment: Igual ojo, porque el timer es un buen recurso, pero para contar el tiempo no es bueno. Tiene delay, perdida de tiempo por lo que tarda en ejecutar los eventos, y tambien en lanzarlos... tambien tenes un pequeño delay en los tiempos en que se ejecuta... no es perfecto...

Comment: @gbianchi de casualidad sabes algun otro metodo para contar el tiempo que sea mas efectivo?

Comment: si si.. usa un [StopWatch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-6.0)

Comment: [`Timer`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-6.0) está pensado para que establezcas un tiempo y una vez termine pase algo. Por eso tiene el evento `Elapsed`. Es como poner el despertador o una cuenta regresiva. Para cronometrar, como dijo @gbianchi es buena idea usar StopWatch.